# Facing problems using gets function in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm Having a problem in xcode. I am using xcode 7.3. I have created a lot of programs. But in some the use of gets/getline function creates problems.
Such in one of my codings, the gets function is just skipped over without any error. I tried to replace it somewhere else, sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
class TESTMATCH
{

private:
int TestCode, NoOfCandidates, CenterReqd;
    char Description[40];



int CALCULATECNTR()
{
    int x;
    x=NoOfCandidates/100+1;
    return x;
}

public:
void GETDATA()
{
    std::cout<<"Enter Details...\n";
    std::cout<<"Enter Test Code: ";
    std::cin>>TestCode;
    std::cout<<"Enter Description: ";
    gets(Description);
    std::cout<<"Enter No. of Candidates: ";
    std::cin>>NoOfCandidates;


    CenterReqd=CALCULATECNTR();
}

void PUTDATA()
{
    std::cout<<"TEST MATCH INFORMATION \n";
    std::cout<<"Test Match Code\t:"<<TestCode;
    std::cout<<"\nDescription\t\t:";
    puts(Description);
    std::cout<<"\nTotal Candidates\t:"<<NoOfCandidates;
    std::cout<<"\nCentres Required\t:"<<CenterReqd;
}



 }TM1;

int main()
{
char a;
do
{
    TM1.GETDATA();
    TM1.PUTDATA();
    std::cout<<"\nWant to Enter More? Y or N?";
    std::cin>>a;
}while (a=='Y' || a=='y');
}'
```

Here's the output:

```
Enter Details...
Enter Test Code: 123
Enter Description: Enter No. of Candidates: 3123
TEST MATCH INFORMATION 
Test Match Code : 123
Description     :

Total Candidates    :3123
Centres Required    :32
Want to Enter More? Y or N?n
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I just don't what to do. I there something wrong with the compiler or with my code? The same problem persisted when I ran it on xcode 6.4 and netbeans, but it ran perfectly on turbo C++. What I posted in output section is as it showed in the output console of xcode.
Please help.

Comment: More than likely, your issue is not with XCode, as XCode is an IDE.

Comment: Be aware of integer division, example 1/2 == 0; 1.0/2.0 == 0.5.

Comment: Coding guideline:  Identifier names IN ALL CAPS are usually used for macros.  Functions names are preferred to be either in all lower case or mixed case.

Comment: Please **edit your post** with correct, expected output and the erroneous output.  Indicate where they differ.

Comment: Pardon my naivete, but where in your code are you using `gets`?  Also, you should be using `cin` if you use `cout`; *"Don't cross the streams."* There are also [buffer overflow issues with `gets`](https://www.google.com/search?q=buffer+overflow+gets&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: The same problem persists on eclipse

Comment: No the naivety is all mine. There should have been gets in place of getline.

Comment: But the same problem persists in use of getline function

Comment: Please help me. I'm really stuck here

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a simple version to test out some concepts:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int TestCode = -1;
    std::string Description;
    int NoOfCandidates = -1;

    std::cout<<"Enter Details...\n";
    std::cout<<"Enter Test Code: ";
    std::cin>>TestCode;
    std::cout<<"Enter Description: ";
    std::getline(std::cin,Description);
    std::cout<<"Enter No. of Candidates: ";
    std::cin>>NoOfCandidates;

    std::cout << "\n\nYour entered:\n"
              << "Description: \"" << Description << "\"\n"
              << "Test code: " << TestCode << "\n"
              << "Number of candidates: " << NoOfCandidates << "\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Using Cygwin with G++ version 5.3.0, I have the following transcript:

```
$ g++ -o gets.exe gets.cpp

$ ./gets.exe
Enter Details...
Enter Test Code: 42
Enter Description: Enter No. of Candidates: 25


Your entered:
Description: ""
Test code: 42
Number of candidates: 25
```

What is happening is that the *newline* character is still in the input buffer when `std::getline` is called.  Let's change the code and ignore the newline.

```
//...
        std::cout<<"Enter Test Code: ";
        std::cin>>TestCode;

/* --> */ std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');  // One method to ignore the newline.

        std::cout<<"Enter Description: ";
//...
```

The transcript:

```
$ g++ -o gets.exe gets.cpp

$ ./gets.exe
Enter Details...
Enter Test Code: 42
Enter Description: Frog
Enter No. of Candidates: 69


Your entered:
Description: "Frog"
Test code: 42
Number of candidates: 69
```

Comment: BTW, is there any way to make the ignore thing constant?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please click on the check mark.

Comment: There are other methods for ignoring the newline, search StackOverflow for "c++ ignore skip newline"